# How to add pg extension to bitnami PostgreSQL image

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, bitnami

I am using bitnami postgres image for deploying database into k8s cluster. The problem occurred when I have tried to add external extension (f.e. plpythonu). Bitnami is not supporting this extension out of the box

I've tried to modify docker image:

```
ARG PG_MAJOR=12
FROM bitnami/postgresql:$PG_MAJOR
ARG PG_MAJOR
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install wget lsb-release gnupg
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install postgresql-plpython3-$PG_MAJOR

USER 1001
```

But I still cannot add the extension to postgresql. Getting error `ERROR:  language "plpythonu" does not exist`